# What is a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

Some definitions says a differential equation is

> a mathematical equation that relates a function with its derivatives

Some say that it is just

> an equation involving derivatives of a function or functions.

If by definition a differential equation relates some function with its derivatives, then how is
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
a differential equation ?

There is no function in it, so how can we call it a differential equation? It has just a derivative of a function equal to 0, it does not relate the function with its derivative.

Comment: on the other hand it has solutions, $y = \rm{constant}$

Comment: You can write it instead as
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+0\cdot y=0$$

Comment: If you don't require the definition of equation (differential or otherwise), then a differential equation is simply any equation of the form $F(t,y(t),y'(t),\ldots ,y^{(n)}(t))=0$, for some $n\in \mathbb N$ and some function $F\colon \mathbb R^{n+1}\to \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yeah that relation doesnt explicitely have to contain y by itself, that falls well into both definitions

Comment: The equation y'=0 is a relation saying that y is any function whose derivative  is zero, to which the constant function y=c is a solution

Comment: I think it's a little unsatisfying that both Git Gud's and Zev's answers say that essentially all equations are degenerate cases of differential equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the second definition is better. $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ would be considered a differential equation. A differential equation doesn't necessarily need to involve the function itself.